# Javascript library for Canvas with relative layout or grid layout

Tags: javascript, canvas, grid, fabricjs

I made a canvas in FabricJs which will be opened in different type of screen sizes. Everything was ok till today. But then I tried to make the canvas export import feature. And now screen resolution makes everything mess when exporting to different resolution size.

I tried to find if I can handle all positions relatively. Better if I can add items using percentage of canvas size.

I didn't find this feature in FabricJs.

1. Is it available any other library? 
   Or
2. Is there any library by which I can place items using grid?? So that I will make grids relative to screen size & then will use that grid for item placement.

Comment: Why you just do not use canvas zooming? it should solve your problem. Please poste a fiddle with your canvas setup and i will show you.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi, I have tried canvas zooming. But I'm not getting any changes on canvas.toJSON() output. Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zrwjm5yn/. It have a console.log of toJSON method on zoomin.